# Infinite loop when making Axios GET Request - Loop Won't Close

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios

I'm a pretty big newb when it comes to working with API's and promises - so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this issue.

The goal is to make a GET request to an API and have those results returned. However, since the API spreads data across multiple pages, I'm going to loop through the API pages until I get back 0 listings.

I'm able to successfully log listings to the console, however, the while loop inside of loopThroughListings never seems to close despite listingsExist being set to false.

Where did I go wrong?

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Loop through multiple pages of listings in the API
function loopThroughListings() {
  let listingsExist = true;

  // Loop through listings until they don't exist
  while(listingsExist) {

    getListing().then(function(listing) {

      if(listing.length < 1 ) {
        // if listings don't exist, stop the loop
        // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
        console.log("No Listings");
        listingsExist = false;
      } else {
        // if listings do exist, log them to console
        console.log(listing);
      }

    });

  }
}

// Return listing data from API
async function getListing(page) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://mlb19.theshownation.com/apis/listings.json?type=Stadium&page=1}`);
    return response.data.listings;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

loopThroughListings();
```

Comment: `getListing()` is asynchronous, therefore the `axios.get` will never finish executing since you effectively have a `while(true){}` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `loopThroughListings` to be `async` and then you can `await getListing()`

Like so:

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Loop through multiple pages of listings in the API
async function loopThroughListings() {
    let listingsExist = true;

    // Loop through listings until they don't exist
    while (listingsExist) {
        const listing = await getListing();
        if (listing.length < 1) {
            // if listings don't exist, stop the loop
            // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
            console.log("No Listings");
            listingsExist = false;
        } else {
            // if listings do exist, log them to console
            console.log(listing);
        }
    }
}

// Return listing data from API
async function getListing(page) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://mlb19.theshownation.com/apis/listings.json?type=Stadium&page=1}`);
        return response.data.listings;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

loopThroughListings();
```

---

Personally, since the while loop will of course run at least once, I'd use `do/while` instead - to me it makes the flow of the code more apparent

```
    do {
        const listing = await getListing();
        if (listing.length < 1) {
            // if listings don't exist, stop the loop
            // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
            console.log("No Listings");
            listingsExist = false;
        } else {
            // if listings do exist, log them to console
            console.log(listing);
        }
    } while(listingsExist);
```

But that's just a matter of opinion